# CPU code runs slow after GPU called

Tags: c++, cuda

I have, in my opinion, a rather strange problem. I have a piece of code that starts with using the GPU to create four matrices which takes 0.15 seconds, then the matrices are copied to the host and put into `cv::Mat` matrices. Thereafter two nested for-loops are used to iterate through the images and perform some computations.

The for-loop runs entirely on the CPU and takes 14 seconds to finish if I have used the GPU to compute the matrices before. If I instead use the CPU all the way, also when computing the four matrices, it takes 2 seconds to compute the matrices, but only 1.2 seconds to run the for-loop.

Why does it take so long time if I use the GPU before the for-loop. The GPU has nothing to do with the GPU.

Another strange thing is that if I after that I have called the GPU and created the `cv::Mat` matrices on the CPU, I visualize an image like this

```
    cv::imshow("Error", Error * 100);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

before the loop, then the loop just takes 1.4 seconds.

**Another strange thing is that if I run diagnostics as adminstrator, it runs perfectly, and faster. Also when profiling the code runs significantly faster.**

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on a 64-bit machine.

Here is the code:

```
void ModelTracker::computeAnalyticLSqRay(const Eigen::VectorXd &Xi, const cv::Mat &depthImg){
LieAlgebra::LieAlgebra lie;
Eigen::MatrixXd A = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(6, 6);
Eigen::VectorXd b = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(6);

// Vectors for rotation and translation
Eigen::Vector3d xi(Xi(0), Xi(1), Xi(2));
Eigen::Vector3d t(Xi(3), Xi(4), Xi(5));

// Vectors for outer derivative
double delta = DELTADERIV;

Eigen::VectorXd XiDX = Xi;
Eigen::VectorXd XiDY = Xi;
Eigen::VectorXd XiDZ = Xi;

XiDX(3) += delta;
XiDY(4) += delta;
XiDZ(5) += delta;

//cv::Mat Error = rayCast(Xi, depthImg);
//cv::Mat ErrorDX = rayCast(XiDX, depthImg);
//cv::Mat ErrorDY = rayCast(XiDY, depthImg);
//cv::Mat ErrorDZ = rayCast(XiDZ, depthImg);

// Here the GPU is called from the function GPURayCast

double t1 = omp_get_wtime();
cv::Mat Error = GPUrayCast(Xi, depthImg);
cv::Mat ErrorDX = GPUrayCast(XiDX, depthImg);
cv::Mat ErrorDY = GPUrayCast(XiDY, depthImg);
cv::Mat ErrorDZ = GPUrayCast(XiDZ, depthImg);
double t2 = omp_get_wtime();
std::cout << t2 - t1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "GPURayCast Done" << std::endl;
cv::imshow("Error", Error * 100);
cv::waitKey(0);
Eigen::MatrixXd Atmp = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(6, 6);
Eigen::VectorXd btmp = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(6, 1);

t1 = omp_get_wtime();
for (int i = 0; i < depthImg.rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < depthImg.cols; ++j){
        double z = depthImg.at<double>(i, j);
        if (!isnan(z)){
            double V0 = Error.at<double>(i, j);
            if (!isnan(V0)){
                Eigen::Vector3d pLocal = reproject3p(j, i, z);
                double V0Dx = ErrorDX.at<double>(i, j);
                double V0Dy = ErrorDY.at<double>(i, j);
                double V0Dz = ErrorDZ.at<double>(i, j);

                if (!isnan(V0Dx) && !isnan(V0Dy) && !isnan(V0Dz)){
                    Eigen::VectorXd grad = getRayAnalyticGradient(xi, t, pLocal, V0, V0Dx, V0Dy, V0Dz, delta, i, j, z);

                    bool gradCheck = checkGradient(grad);

                    if (gradCheck){
                        Atmp += grad*grad.transpose();
                        btmp += V0*grad;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
t2 = omp_get_wtime();
std::cout << "Time for computing matrices: " << t2 - t1<< std::endl;
//std::cout << btmp << std::endl;
ALsq = Atmp;
bLsq = btmp;
}
```

GPUrayCast:

```
cv::Mat ModelTracker::GPUrayCast(const Eigen::VectorXd &Xi, const cv::Mat &depthImg){
LieAlgebra::LieAlgebra lie;
double *error = new double[depthImg.rows*depthImg.cols];
memset(error, 0, depthImg.cols*depthImg.rows);
Eigen::Matrix4d camera = lie.getTransfMatrix(Xi);
double ptrCamera[12] = { 0 };
cpyToCamera(ptrCamera, camera);
double3 gridStart = { start(0), start(1), start(2) };
GPURayCast(error, depthImg.rows, depthImg.cols, fx, fy, cx, cy, RESOLUTION, step, MAXITR, gridStart, MAXDISTANCE, RAYTHRESHOLD, ptrCamera);
cv::Mat tmp =  getErrorMatrix(error, depthImg.rows, depthImg.cols);
delete [] error;
return tmp;
}
```

GPURayCast: (in the .cu-file)

```
extern "C" void GPURayCast(double *target, const int rows, const int cols, const double fx, const double fy, const double cx, const double cy, const int resolution, const double gridStep, const int maxItr, const double3 gridStart, const int maxDistance, const double rayThreshold, double *camera){
uploadGlobalCamera(camera);

const int nbrOfBlocksX = (rows) / L + ((rows) % L != 0 ? 1 : 0);
const int nbrOfBlocksY = cols / L + (cols % L != 0 ? 1 : 0);
const int BXBY = nbrOfBlocksX * nbrOfBlocksY;

dim3 Blocks(nbrOfBlocksX, nbrOfBlocksY);
dim3 Threads(L, L);


CudaSafeCall(cudaMemset(devTarget, 0, rows*cols*sizeof(double)));

rayCast << <Blocks, Threads >> >(devGrid, devDepthImg, rows, cols, fx, fy, cx, cy, resolution, devTarget, gridStep, maxItr, gridStart, maxDistance, rayThreshold);
CudaSafeCall(cudaThreadSynchronize());
CudaCheckError();
CudaSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(target, devTarget, rows*cols*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
}
```

Doing everything on CPU (Note that the for-loops are exactly the same as in void `ModelTracker::computeAnalyticLSqRay` above):

```
void ModelTracker::CPUcomputeAnalyticLSqRay(const Eigen::VectorXd &Xi, const cv::Mat &depthImg){
LieAlgebra::LieAlgebra lie;
Eigen::MatrixXd A = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(6, 6);
Eigen::VectorXd b = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(6);

// Vectors for rotation and translation
Eigen::Vector3d xi(Xi(0), Xi(1), Xi(2));
Eigen::Vector3d t(Xi(3), Xi(4), Xi(5));

// Vectors for outer derivative
double delta = DELTADERIV;

Eigen::VectorXd XiDX = Xi;
Eigen::VectorXd XiDY = Xi;
Eigen::VectorXd XiDZ = Xi;

//Eigen::VectorXd XiRX = Xi;
//Eigen::VectorXd XiRY = Xi;
//Eigen::VectorXd XiRZ = Xi;


XiDX(3) += delta;
XiDY(4) += delta;
XiDZ(5) += delta;

double t1 = omp_get_wtime();
cv::Mat Error = rayCast(Xi, depthImg);
cv::Mat ErrorDX = rayCast(XiDX, depthImg);
cv::Mat ErrorDY = rayCast(XiDY, depthImg);
cv::Mat ErrorDZ = rayCast(XiDZ, depthImg);
double t2 = omp_get_wtime();
std::cout << t2 - t1 << std::endl;
//double t1 = omp_get_wtime();
//cv::Mat Error = GPUrayCast(Xi, depthImg);
//cv::Mat ErrorDX = GPUrayCast(XiDX, depthImg);
//cv::Mat ErrorDY = GPUrayCast(XiDY, depthImg);
//cv::Mat ErrorDZ = GPUrayCast(XiDZ, depthImg);
//double t2 = omp_get_wtime();
//std::cout << t2 - t1 << std::endl;
//std::cout << "GPURayCast Done" << std::endl;
//cv::imshow("Error", Error * 100);
//cv::waitKey(0);
Eigen::MatrixXd Atmp = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(6, 6);
Eigen::VectorXd btmp = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(6, 1);

t1 = omp_get_wtime();
for (int i = 0; i < depthImg.rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < depthImg.cols; ++j){
        double z = depthImg.at<double>(i, j);
        if (!isnan(z)){
            double V0 = Error.at<double>(i, j);
            if (!isnan(V0)){
                Eigen::Vector3d pLocal = reproject3p(j, i, z);
                double V0Dx = ErrorDX.at<double>(i, j);
                double V0Dy = ErrorDY.at<double>(i, j);
                double V0Dz = ErrorDZ.at<double>(i, j);

                if (!isnan(V0Dx) && !isnan(V0Dy) && !isnan(V0Dz)){
                    Eigen::VectorXd grad = getRayAnalyticGradient(xi, t, pLocal, V0, V0Dx, V0Dy, V0Dz, delta, i, j, z);

                    bool gradCheck = checkGradient(grad);

                    if (gradCheck){
                        Atmp += grad*grad.transpose();
                        btmp += V0*grad;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
t2 = omp_get_wtime();
std::cout << "Time for computing matrices: " << t2 - t1 << std::endl;
//std::cout << btmp << std::endl;
ALsq = Atmp;
bLsq = btmp;
}
```

getErrorMatrix():

```
cv::Mat ModelTracker::getErrorMatrix(double *error, const int rows, const int cols){
cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_64FC1);
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
        tmp.at<double>(i, j) = error[j + i*cols];
    }
}
return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Possibly, when you do all your computation in CPU or if you visualize the matrix, it is already in cash which makes your loops fast.

Comment: Ok, but why would it not be otherwise? By the way I am using Visual Studio 2013 64-bit.

Comment: I am not an expert on CUDA or NVidia, but I know that generally cost of copying data prevents using GPU in most applications. Particularly, for matrix N*N, you usually need to offload O(N^3) operation to GPU to make it faster than CPU.

Comment: Sure, but that is already done when I go into the for-loops. And the raycast four times takes 0.16 seconds including copying back and forth to the GPU, compared to 2.2 seconds using only the CPU. The question is why pure CPU-code suddenly is extremely slow. It is probably connected to the GPU somehow, but I cannot see it.

Comment: The copying is already done, but it might be a copy to the main memory, not to the cash of the core that does further calculation. Again, I am not an expert on this hardware...

Answer (score 1):

Because of the strange behavior I started to suspect that it was something with the settings in Visual Studio 2013. It turned out that even if I was building with the Release version, when I launched the program it was with debugging. Adding the button "Start without debugging" did the trick, (or ctrl-F5). In other words, just a silly mistake by me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which calls in your code could possibly do it, but it seems likely that your GPU calculation includes a step that moves the data into VRAM, and then instead of copying the result back, your GPU has a shared-address programming model and it is simply mapping the VRAM into the address space of the CPU code, such that every subsequent access costs a PCI transaction.

Or perhaps the GPU driver is changing page table flags on the buffer you passed in, such as marking pages as non-cacheable, in order to make it usable for DMA.

Try following the GPU operation by immediately cloning the entirety of your data into a brand-new buffer, wholly in CPU memory and never seen by the GPU driver, and use that copy for the subsequent calculation.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. In the for-loop I am reading from Error, ErrorDx, ErrorDy and ErrorDz, but they are cv::Mat matrices (opencv) which are created on the CPU. Why would the result in PCI-transactions?

Comment: Well, we don’t know since we don’t see the code of getErrorMatrix. For all I know, cv::Mat could be created from existing memory. But looking at what is passed to getErrorMatrix, it seems unlikely.

Comment: I add getErrorMatrix()

Comment: @Erik: And you pass it into the GPU kernel, correct?  So if the GPU does DMA on that buffer, it might affect your later reads.  It's a bit hard to follow what's going on here because you seem to be passing a lot of data around through class members and not function parameters.